# Get fitted effects from a model with an rcs term

Tags: r, modeling, effects

I would like to get fitted values from a linear model that includes a restricted cubic spline term fit via `rms::rcs()`, to pass into an effects plot. The issue is that the package I typically use to get fitted values, `effects`, throws an error when I try to pass a model with an `rcs` term.

Here's a minimal reprex:

```
library(rms)
library(effects)
mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ rcs(Sepal.Width, 3), iris)
Effect("Sepal.Width", mod)
##Error in rcspline.eval(x, nk = nknots, inclx = TRUE, pc = pc, fractied = fractied) : knots not specified, and < 6 non-missing observations
```

I have tried debugging this error, but I can't arrive at how `rcspline.eval()` got 6+ NAs in `x` and non-specified `nknots`. How do I deal with this error? Alternatively, is there another package out there that can get fitted effects from a model with an `rcs` term?

Comment: I would have expected that Predict or predict would give you what you expect. The `rms` planet is not in orbit around the `effects` center of gravity.

Comment: Can you give an example as an answer? I looked into predict but couldn't wrap my head around how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users of the rms environment will need to use the specialized functions that support its activities:

```
 library(rms)
 ddist <- datadist(iris)  # need both datadist and options 
 options(datadist='ddist')
 mod <- ols(Sepal.Length ~ rcs(Sepal.Width, 3), iris)  # need ols rather than lm
 plot( Predict(mod, Sepal.Width))  # Predict can be done in 2 or 3 dimension
        # gives a lattice output
```

[image]

Comment: I see. I'm not sure if this solution will work for me since I ultimately want to apply this to a mixed-effects model, and AFAIK rms's builtin modeling functions don't allow random effects

Comment: So you posed a question that didn't include the essential criteria.

Comment: I didn't know where the sticking point would be. You did answer the question, so I'll accept.

Comment: My understanding is that the mgcv package provides cubic splines via the `s()` function and supports mixed effects.